# Populate select options from database to dynamic select option using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

From the database I have selected the names of the `members` as the `select` options. With `jQuery`, I have a dynamic Add button that adds new select field with the `append` function. But what could be the standard way to pass my select options generated by `php` in the append?

I have researched for a while but could not get it working. So any suggestions would be really helpful.

This is the page structure. It looks messy but please have a look at it. I have passed the `$members` as `<?php echo $members; ?>` in a static select that already is there from the beginning, but for the dynamic ones, I have created a variable `var members` and tried to pass it in the `append` but it is not working.

```
<?php
   require_once 'db_connect.php';

   $members = '';
   $query = "SELECT memberID, memberName FROM members";
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $members .= '<option value="'.$row["memberID"].'">'.$row["memberName"].'</option>';
   }
   ?>
<script> 
   var members = "<?php echo $members; ?>";

   $(document).ready(function() {
          var fixHelperModified = function(e, div) {
                var $originals = div.children();
                var $helper = div.clone();
                $helper.children().each(function(index) {
                   $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
                });
                return $helper;
             },
             updateIndex = function() {
                $('div.index').each(function(i) {
                   $(this).html(i + 1);
                });
             };
          $("#add").sortable({
             helper: fixHelperModified,
             stop: updateIndex
          }).disableSelection();
          $("#addNew").click(function() {
             $('#add').append("<div class='row rem' id='move'><div class='col-md-1 index'>1. </div><div class='col-md-9'><select name='members[]'><option value=''>Select member</option>"+members+"</select></div><div class='col-md-1'><button class='delete btn btn-warning btn-xs'>Delete</button></div></div>");
             updateIndex();
          });
          $("body").on('click', '#add .delete', function() {
             $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
             updateIndex();
          });
       });
</script>
<form method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-name">Members</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
               <div id='add'>
                  <div class='row rem' id='move'>
                     <div class='col-md-1 index'>1. </div>
                     <div class='col-md-9'>
                        <select name='members[]'>
                           <option value=''>Select member</option>
                           <?php echo $members; ?>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class='col-md-1'>
                        <button class='delete btn btn-warning btn-xs'>Delete</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                     <button id='addNew' type="button" href="#">Add another</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" name="submitSave" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Here is a snippet of the form without the `php` if you need to see the `jQuery` in action.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var fixHelperModified = function(e, div) {
             var $originals = div.children();
             var $helper = div.clone();
             $helper.children().each(function(index) {
                $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
             });
             return $helper;
          },
          updateIndex = function() {
             $('div.index').each(function(i) {
                $(this).html(i + 1);
             });
          };
       $("#add").sortable({
          helper: fixHelperModified,
          stop: updateIndex
       }).disableSelection();
       $("#addNew").click(function() {
          $('#add').append("<div class='row rem' id='move'><div class='col-md-1 index'>1. </div><div class='col-md-9'><select name='members[]'><option value=''>Select member</option></select></div><div class='col-md-1'><button class='delete btn btn-warning btn-xs'>Delete</button></div></div>");
          updateIndex();
       });
       $("body").on('click', '#add .delete', function() {
          $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
          updateIndex();
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-name">Members</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
               <div id='add'>
                  <div class='row rem' id='move'>
                     <div class='col-md-1 index'>1. </div>
                     <div class='col-md-9'>
                        <select name='members[]'>
                        <option value=''>Select member</option>
                        <option value='First'>First</option>
                        <option value='Second'>Second</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class='col-md-1'>
                        <button class='delete btn btn-warning btn-xs'>Delete</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                     <button id='addNew' type="button" href="#">Add another</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" name="submitSave" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: to begin with this will break your javascript already at the beginning : `var members = "<?php echo $members; ?>";` and then again where you insert it into the `select` element. Fix the quotation marks maybe it runs.

Comment: try replace `var members = <?php echo (string)$members; ?>;`

Comment: I have replaced it with `var members = <?php echo (string)$members; ?>;` and passed it as `"+members+"` in the append. But it still is not working. Any suggestion? @IvanKaraman

Comment: each option have double quotation marks and u put string inside same marks, if i corect understood its breaks your code, try wrap inside single quotation or use `var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($myVarValue); ?>;`

Comment: Thanks! It worked finally. `var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($myVarValue); ?>;` was the perfect solution. Thanks a lot for your effort. I really appreciate it.  :)  @IvanKaraman

Comment: Can you please give this as an answer so that I'll be able to mark it as solved? @IvanKaraman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each option have double quotation marks and u put string inside same marks, if i correct understood it will break your code, try wrap inside single quotation or use `var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($myVarValue); ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

I dont get you want to use jquery to add a select option from the list of already generated options(generated with php) each time a user clicks the add button?

Answer (score 0):

If thats what you want? you can just echo the php into a javascript array

```
<script>
var members = []; // this is the javascript array been initialized
<?php
require_once 'db_connect.php';

$members = '';
$query = "SELECT memberID, memberName FROM members";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$i=0 // index for the array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$raw_option = '<option   value="'.$row["memberID"].'">'.$row["memberName"].'</option>';
$option = htmlentities($raw_options); // there might be quotation that could break your javascript 
echo "members[{$i}] = '{$option}';"; // echoing the javascript first semi column is for javascript and second for php


$i++; // incrementing the index for the array
}
?>
</script>
```

Then the jquery add button can just pick each options from the members array

Comment: Wow! Thanks let me try. Can you just include the `append` section in the answer please? I'm having trouble with quotation marks inside the append.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working I'm afraid.

Comment: if you used the htmlentities you wont have problem with quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your many code but if what you want to do is add an option when clicked this is what i think should work

```
<select name='members' id="members_select">
<option value=''>Select member</option>
</select>
<button id="add">Add Option</button>
<script>
var current_member = 0; // global variable that tells what part index of the members array we currently are..
add_button = document.getElementById("add");
add_button.addEventListener('click') = function(){
   // i imagine the members array above is already set
  $('#members_select').append(members[current_member]);
  current_member++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Ivan Karaman has already solved the problem. But thanks for your view of the alternatives.  :)

Comment: Ok... I  had to add extra cause they wont let me post comments less than 15 char